# How to attach adapter in fragment after data synced in service

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have written my GeoQuery Code in the Service which also implements location service. I want the adapter to be synchronised in service class and after the data has been loaded I want it to be attached to RecyclerView in the Fragment here is the code I am implementing in the Service.

```
  private void startGeoQuery() {
        query = geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, 2);
        Log.d(TAG, "center: " + center.toString() + ", radius: " + 2);
        query.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Key " + key + " entered the search area at [" + location.latitude + "," + location.longitude + "]");
                DatabaseReference tempRef = mFirebaseRef.child(key);
                tempRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        // I  add the deal only if it doesn't exist already in the adapter
                        String key = snapshot.getKey();
                        if (!mAdapter.exists(key)) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "item added " + key);
                            mAdapter.addSingle(snapshot);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else {
                            //...otherwise I will update the record
                            Log.d(TAG, "item updated: " + key);
                            mAdapter.update(snapshot, key);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {
                Log.d(TAG, "deal " + key + " is no longer in the search area");
                mAdapter.remove(key);
                isListEmpty(); // Method from the Fragment

            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Key " + key + " moved within the search area to [%f,%f]", location.latitude, location.longitude));
                DatabaseReference tempRef = mFirebaseRef.child(key);
                tempRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        // I  add the deal only if it doesn't exist already in the adapter
                        String key = snapshot.getKey();
                        if (!mAdapter.exists(key)) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "item added " + key);
                            mAdapter.addSingle(snapshot);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else {
                            //...otherwise I will update the record
                            Log.d(TAG, "item updated: " + key);
                            mAdapter.update(snapshot, key);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                Log.d(TAG, "All initial data has been loaded and events have been fired!");
                isListEmpty();  //Method from the Fragment
                mActiveGeoQuery = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "There was an error with this query: " + error);
                mActiveGeoQuery = false;
            }
        });
        bindRecyclerView(); //Method from the Fragment
    }
```

This is the code in the Fragment Class

```
public void bindRecyclerView() {
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

 private void isListEmpty() {
        if (mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
            filterList(key);
        }
    }

public void filterList(String query) {
        if (query.equals("")) {
            mAdapter = new FirebasePostsQueryAdapter(mFirebaseRef.limitToFirst(20), R.layout.geo_feeds_items, getActivity(), PostViewHolder.class);
        } else {
            mAdapter = new FirebasePostsQueryAdapter(mFirebaseRef.orderByValue().startAt(query), R.layout.geo_feeds_items, getActivity(), PostViewHolder.class);
        }
        bindRecyclerView();
    }
```